# Determining the value to which the sequence $a_n=\frac{n!}{n^n}$ converges.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

How can it be deduced that the sequence $a_n=\dfrac{n!}{n^n}$ converges to $0$? I can reasonably infer this to be true, because I see the pattern as $n$ approaches larger values, but I am unsure of how to to evaluate $\lim a_n=L$ to show that $L=0$.

Comment: Stirling's approximation.

Comment: @RobertIsrael We've never discussed what you speak of in our class. Do you know of a more elementary solution to determining this limit?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Write $\frac{n!}{n^n}$ as 
$$
\frac{n}{n}\frac{n-1}{n} \cdots \frac{1}{n}
$$
and as you can see by the last factor of this, $\frac{n!}{n^n} \leq \frac1n$ (because all the other factors are less than $1$).
Obviously we have $0 \leq \frac{n!}{n^n} \leq \frac 1n$ , so we know that it has to converge to $0$

Comment: Wouldn't I have to squeeze it so that $0 < \frac{n!}{n^n} \leq \frac{1}{n}$ to show that it must converge to 0?

Comment: yes, but of course $0<\frac{n!}{n^n}$ holds

Comment: In fact, we can find the speed of convergence by looking at the ratio of successive terms.  We find that $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\to e^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

For $n > 1$,
$$\frac{n!}{n^n} = \prod_\limits{i = 1}^{n}\frac{i}{n} = \frac{1}{n} \prod_\limits{i = 2}^{n}\frac{i}{n} \leq \frac{1}{n}$$
It is bounded by a sequence $\frac{1}{n}$ that converges to zero, so it must converge to zero to.

Comment: $\{\frac1n\}_{n\ge 1}$ is a sequence, not a series!

Comment: @Mercy indeed, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}&=\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\frac{n^n}{n!}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n}\\\\
&\to e^{-1}\\\\
&<1
\end{align}$$

---

Of course, Stirling's formula is the better way to go.  Although the OP mentioned that that topic has not yet been discussed, I thought that it might be instructive to show how it can be used here.  So, here we go ...

Stirling's formula is given by

$$n!=\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\left(1+O\left(\frac1n\right)\right)$$

Thus, we have

$$\frac{n!}{n^n}=\sqrt{2\pi n}e^{-n}\left(1+O\left(\frac1n\right)\right)$$

which clearly goes to zero as $n \to \infty$.

It is also worth remarking that from Stirling's formula we obtain

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=e^{-1}\left(1+O\left(\frac1n\right)\right)$$

which goes to $e^{-1}$ as $n\to \infty$ as expected.